# iptables port forwarding rule ignored

Tags: iptables

I want to forward the traffic from port 1111 to port 2222. So I execute the `iptables` command, but it seems that, somehow, the rule is not being saved.

```
# iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 1111 -j REDIRECT --to-port 2222
# iptables -L -v
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 24845 packets, 35M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 24720 packets, 35M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

I would expect that the `iptables -L -v` command would show the rule that I just created. It works for other rules but for this one it doesn't.

Am I missing something?

Comment: By default, the `filter` table is used. Try `iptables -t nat -nvL`.

Comment: Thank you, it works. Please feel free to add the comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the `filter` table is used. Try `iptables -t nat -nvL`.